# Transfering files with FTP

Tags: ftp

How can I transfer files to and from a remote system using FTP?

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you were asking for. I didn't notice the firefox-beta tag until I had already edited it and answered it. If I was wrong, please roll-back my edit and edit the question to ask what you really want to do.

Comment: @Oli: There's a small glitch if you use the Places > Connect to Server thing.  Firefox defaults to being the primary thing for the FTP protocol, you'll need to connect, then open a nautilus browser and browse to your connection that's listed to use Nautilus as the FTP transfer system.

Comment: Can you clarify "transfer" and the server/client role? I.e. do you need help with setting up the FTP server? Do you just need to download a file from the FTP server, or upload files as well?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Places menu and click "Connect to Server". Select the right type of FTP server (public or private) and click Connect. From there it's drag and drop.

If you need the command line, do the above and then in your terminal look in `~/.gvfs/`. The FTP server gets mounted as a subdirectory in there.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. I am particularly partial to the [gFTP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gFTP) client.  It provides a nice GUI interface and supports multiple protocols beyond just straight FTP. You can install it from synaptic or from a command line doing `sudo apt-get install gftp`.
2. The Firefox plug-in "FireFTP" is a great package.  It runs inside Firefox and like gFTP provides multiple protocols beyond just FTP.